# Fixing "Invalid OpCode" Truffle Error with Openzeppelin Library Installed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache, openzeppelin

## Hi. I am new to blockchain development. I am currently using Solidity + Truffle + Ganache on VS Code. I am also using the Openzeppelin Library.

#### So I created this very simple contract that basically is an ERC20 Token (code below):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract SampleToken is ERC20 {

    constructor () ERC20 ("Sample Token", "SAMPLE") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

}
```

#### Here is my truffle.config.js:

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation, and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration
 *
 * Hands-off deployment with Infura
 * --------------------------------
 *
 * Do you have a complex application that requires lots of transactions to deploy?
 * Use this approach to make deployment a breeze ️:
 *
 * Infura deployment needs a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign transactions before they're sent to a remote public node.
 * Infura accounts are available for free at : https://infura.io/register
 *
 * You'll need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. You can store your secrets  in a .env file.
 * In your project root, run `$ npm install dotenv`.
 * Create .env (which should be .gitignored) and declare your MNEMONIC
 * and Infura PROJECT_ID variables inside.
 * For example, your .env file will have the following structure:
 *
 * MNEMONIC = <Your 12 phrase mnemonic>
 * PROJECT_ID = <Your Infura project id>
 *
 * Deployment with Truffle Dashboard (Recommended for best security practice)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Are you concerned about security and minimizing rekt status ?
 * Use this method for best security:
 *
 * Truffle Dashboard lets you review transactions in detail, and leverages
 * MetaMask for signing, so there's no need to copy-paste your mnemonic.
 * More details can be found at :
 *
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-the-truffle-dashboard/
 */

// require('dotenv').config();
// const { MNEMONIC, PROJECT_ID } = process.env;

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a managed Ganache instance for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache, geth, or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    //
    // An additional network, but with some advanced options…
    // advanced: {
    //   port: 8777,             // Custom port
    //   network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    //   gas: 8500000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    //   gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    //   from: <address>,        // Account to send transactions from (default: accounts[0])
    //   websocket: true         // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    //
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // Note: It's important to wrap the provider as a function to ensure truffle uses a new provider every time.
    // goerli: {
    //   provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${PROJECT_ID}`),
    //   network_id: 5,       // Goerli's id
    //   confirmations: 2,    // # of confirmations to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
    //   timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
    //   skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    // },
    //
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    //   provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://network.io`),
    //   network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    //   production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.20",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled:
  // false to enabled: true. The default storage location can also be
  // overridden by specifying the adapter settings, as shown in the commented code below.
  //
  // NOTE: It is not possible to migrate your contracts to truffle DB and you should
  // make a backup of your artifacts to a safe location before enabling this feature.
  //
  // After you backed up your artifacts you can utilize db by running migrate as follows:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all
  //
  // db: {
  //   enabled: false,
  //   host: "127.0.0.1",
  //   adapter: {
  //     name: "indexeddb",
  //     settings: {
  //       directory: ".db"
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
};
```

#### Here is my migrations file:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require ("SampleToken");

module.exports = function(_deployer) {
// Use deployer to state migration tasks.

_deployer.deploy (Migrations);

};
```

It's a very basic smart contract. Basically baby steps into my learning.

It compiles fine, but when I execute `truffle migrate` to deploy the contract, i get the following results from the terminal:

```
Compiling your contracts...Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/SampleToken.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/www/html/TruffleToken/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1710763574_sample_token.js
==============================

   Deploying 'SampleToken'
   --------------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"SampleToken" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"SampleToken" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:330:1
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v20.11.1
> Compiling ./contracts/HighTableToken.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/www/html/TruffleToken/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6.Emscripten.clang
```

#### it says invalid OpCode.

As per my googling abilities, it is because of *"The error "invalid opcode" can occur when deploying a contract to Ganache due to the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode, which is only supported on ETH mainnet. Other chains can't find this opcode, which can cause the error."*

Subsequently, I am recommended to lower my solidity version to a version that is lower than 0.8.20.

#### However, the Openzeppelin Library's pragma is set to this version. It is a hassle to manually edit the actual files one by one. Possible solution, but very naive. Is there a way to circumvent this error, or, well, edit the pragmas all at once if no code solution is possible?

Answer (score 0):

so this happened to me i ran "truffle develop" in the terminal and then i wrote "migrate" and it worked .Hope it helped!